# When should einige be followed by the singular/plural?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number

**How to know whether *einige* should be followed by the plural or by the singular?**

The examples below seem to suggest that both options are possible.

```
Exemple 1. "Als er sich für einige Zeit bei mir aufhielt."      <- sing

Exemple 2. "Vor einiger Zeit schon."                            <- sing

Exemple 3. "Wir müssen einige Änderungen vornehmen              <- plur

Exemple 4. "... einige Beispiele zur Nutzung des Wortes ...     <- plur
```

Is *Zeit* an exception, or an example of a class of words that remains singular after einige?

Comment: Actually there is no difference to English here. "Für einige Zeit" = "For some time", "For some times" doesn't make much sense in English either. See this question on SE English: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43648/for-some-time-vs-for-some-times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If *einige* is used in the sense of English *several* then it takes the plural: *einige Änderungen*, *einige Beispiele*.

If it's used in the sense of English *some* it takes the singular: *einige Zeit*, *einige Hoffnung*.

An exception is *einige Mal* as a colloquial form of *einige Male*